# How to call a specific Advice from Join point in Spring AOP?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-aop, spring-annotations

I am trying to create Spring AOP implementation in which wherever I will place a specific annotation, respective advises (Before, After, Around etc.) will execute. 
Below is the customized annotation:

```
import java.lang.annotation.Documented;
import java.lang.annotation.Inherited;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;

@Documented
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Inherited
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface LogExecutionTime {

}
```

The respective aspect is as:

```
import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.After;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Aspect
@Component
public class ExampleAspect {

    @Before("@annotation(LogExecutionTime)")
    public void logExecutionTimeBefore(JoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable 
    {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        long executionTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;

        System.out.println(joinPoint.getSignature() + " executed in " + 
        executionTime + "ms");
    }

    @After("@annotation(LogExecutionTime)")
    public void logExecutionTimeAfter(JoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable 
    {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        long executionTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;

        System.out.println(joinPoint.getSignature() + " executed in " + 
        executionTime + "ms");
    }

}
```

The following places I am weaving the advices:

```
import sample.annotation.LogExecutionTime;

public class Test {

    @LogExecutionTime
    public void serve() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t = new Test();
        try {
            t.serve();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Now my requirement is if I can call any specific advice from the Join Point itself like @LogExecutionTime(Run only Before Advice) or @LogExecutionTime(Run only After Advice).

Comment: Your requirement is incomprehensible to me. Please explain it better. What is "call any specific advice from the Join Point itself" supposed to mean? Rather explain **what** the aspect should do, not **how** you believe it should do it.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Suppose any method( serve() method for example) in the Test class want to have only Before annotated method (which is logExecutionTimeBefore) from the Aspect to get executed, not all the aspect methods (logExecutionTimeBefore,   logExecutionTimeAfter or any if present) should get executed, which is the default behaviour of the AOP.

Comment: I still don't get it. AOP works like this: The aspect knows which joinpoint it needs/wants to target in order to implement a cross-cutting concern. The code itself does not need to or even should not know that an aspect is operating on it. So what the test class wants, is irrelevant. The only relevant thing is whether there are joinpoints in it matched by any advice's pointcut. So if you as an aspect developer want the aspect to behave in a certain way, formulate your pointcuts and advices accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you can't test it from a non Spring container as you have tried in your test, second you should use an around advice for the aspect.

Based on the [Spring Boot Example Application](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/)

Here is the annotation

```
@Documented
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Inherited
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface LogExecutionTime {
}
```

Here is the aspect

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class LogAspect {

    private List<String> messages = new ArrayList<>();

    @Around("@annotation(hello.LogExecutionTime)")
    public Object handelLogging(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {

        Object proceed = null;
        StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch();
        stopWatch.start();
        proceed = joinPoint.proceed();
        stopWatch.stop();
        messages.add("method " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName() + " took " + stopWatch.getTotalTimeMillis() + "ms");
        return proceed;
    }

    public List<String> getMessages() {
        return messages;
    }
}
```

Here is a test service

```
@Service
public class FooService {

    @LogExecutionTime
    public void doSomething() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500l);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Here is a test

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class LogAspectTest {

    @Autowired
    private FooService service;

    @Autowired
    private LogAspect aspect;

    @Test
    public void test1() throws Exception {
        service.doSomething();
        assertEquals(1, aspect.getMessages().size());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I get it that aop cannot be triggered from a non spring component. But question still exists that how to call a specific advice, like I want only Before advice to get triggered or only Around advice to get triggered.

Comment: Still every advice whether before or after or around, all are executing. I want a way to trigger any one class Fooservice.